# Does the SR from Celestial Template and Spell Resistance stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a character who recently acquired the Celestial Template, which gives:

> Damage Reduction: 10/Magic
>   Spell Resistance: 19

If I cast the cleric spell Spell Resistance as a 10th level cleric, which says in part:

> Subject gains SR 22.

Would these SRs stack, or use the highest number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. SR from multiple sources does not stack, you use only the highest number.

From the bottom of the [description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellResistance) of spell resistance:

> Spell resistance does not stack. It overlaps.

Answer (score 4):

You would use the higher number. I am not sitting here with my DMG

> Spell resistance does not stack. It overlaps. [SRD Refrence](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellResistance)

Comment: I went ahead and edited the reference in to the accepted answer.  (If there's some small thing missing from an existing answer, it's probably better to add to it rather than leave a new one.)

Comment: We posted at like the same time. When I was typing my answer his wasn't there